# RecyclerView with ListAdapter freeze when loading items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I have a dashboard with a bottom navigation with 5 pages. In one of these, I have a RecyclerView where I am loading more or less 20 item.
The problem is that when I click on the bottom navigation the page where this RecyclerView is located, there is a micro freeze that doesn't make the switch between the pages smooth, since I also have an animation on the bottom navigation. If I load 100 item this freeze increase.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I remove that micro freeze? I imagine that the app needs time to render the list, but i don't want the all UI to freeze. If the RecyclerView needs all that time to render, i would like only the RecyclerView to be displayed later, without blocking the UI.

The initialization of the RecyclerView is this:

Fragment

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupView()
        setupObservers()
    }

    private fun setupView() {

        adapterRecipeSections = RecipeCategoriesAdapter(::onItemClick)

        binding.recyclerRecipeSections.apply {
            layoutManager =
                    GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            addItemDecoration(
                    GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, 8, requireContext())
            )
            adapter = adapterRecipeSections
        }
    }

    private fun setupObservers() {
        viewModel.recipesContent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapterRecipeSections.submitList(it)
        }
    }
```

Adapter

```
class RecipeCategoriesAdapter(
        private val onItemClick: () -> Unit
) : ListAdapter<RecipeItemUI, RecipeCategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>(StandardDiffUtil()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemBinding = CardTitleAndSubtitleBottomWithBackgroundBinding
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItem(getItem(position), onItemClick)
    }

    class ViewHolder(
            private val itemBinding: CardTitleAndSubtitleBottomWithBackgroundBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {

        fun bindItem(section: RecipeItemUI, onItemClick: () -> Unit) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
    private val _recipesContent: MutableLiveData<MutableList<RecipeItemUI>> = MutableLiveData()
    val recipesContent: LiveData<MutableList<RecipeItemUI>> = _recipesContent

    init {
        fetchRecipesContent()
    }

    private fun fetchRecipesContent() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _recipesContent.value = dashboardRepo.fetchRecipeContent()
        }
    }
```

Repository

```
    override suspend fun fetchRecipeContent(): MutableList<RecipeItemUI> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mutableListOf(
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Dolci", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Aperitivi", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Long drinks", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Sour", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Sparkling", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Colazione", ""),
                    RecipeItemUI("Dolci", "")
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following paging library made by google.The Paging library helps you load and display pages of data from a larger dataset from local storage or over network. It will not freeze or block but will smooth UI.

Link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview

Comment: doesn't it require that also my api service / local database implement pagination?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved this, the problem was that I had the RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView, which caused all the views to be loaded at once.